# How to make a function executed when to switch to a specific page using QWizard and QWizardPage

Tags: qt4, wizard

I am creating a wizard program(like an installable program), now I want to execute a function when I click on `next` button, say I am in page `Info` and the next page is `register`, now if I clicked on `next` button, it should execute a function I define. How I can do that?

Comment: Have you looked into the currentIdChanged(int) signal on QWizard?